# Summarize cost for each project while referering to values in list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to set up an excel sheet for next years travel expenses. Each trip is related to a specific project, and I want to summarize the travel expenses for each project.
My issue is that I have a predefined list of trips with distances associated to it. So when summarizing the travel expenses it needs to calculate what is the total distance traveled for that project and multiply it with the "Cost/km". Also, I have a column indicating if it was a return trip, so preferably the distance should be multiplied with 2 if the answer is "Yes".

The only thing I could think of was stringing together a bunch of COUNTIFS() multiplied with the distance. However, it is not a very flexible way of doing it and not elegant at all. So I am curious if anyone have ideas of better ways to do this.

[Screenshot of the table in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGxwl.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: The return trip should multiplied with 2? Why the No. of trip for Tes is 3 but not 5?

Answer (score 0):

I added another column to your base table - getting that `XLOOKUP` to work within `SUMIF` started hurting.

[image]

The formula for Cost in E4 is:
`=XLOOKUP($B$4:$B$7,$G$9:$G$13,$H$9:$H$13)*IF($C$4:$C$7="Yes",2,1)*$H$15`

Projects in G4 is:
`=UNIQUE($D$4:$D$7)`

No. of Trips in H4 is:
`=COUNTIF($D$4:$D$7,G4#)`

Travel Cost in I4 is:
`=SUMIF(D4:D7,G4#,E4#)`

---

I was hoping I could use:
`=SUMIF(D4:D7,G4#,XLOOKUP($B$4:$B$7,$G$9:$G$13,$H$9:$H$13)*IF($C$4:$C$7="Yes",2,1)*$H$15)`

but that gives 'there's a problem with this formula' error message and I haven't figured a solution out  yet.
[image]

**Edit:**
On a side note it would be better to turn your data tables into actual tables (Select cells & press Ctrl+T)

[image]

Your formula would then be, for example, `=XLOOKUP([@Trip],TripTable[Trips],TripTable[Distance (km)])*IF([@Return]="Yes",2,1)*CostPerKM` and formula will automatically extend as you add new projects or Trips/Distance.